# How can I type this into a calculator?

Tags: python

In a textbook I am asked to calculate an expression using a calculator: $$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(e^{22}\right)$$

I tried using:

```
0.5*log(exp**22)
```

This returned an error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/56.412575950366508090/sympy/sympy/core/decorators.py", line 91, in __sympifyit_wrapper return func(a, b) File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/56.412575950366508090/sympy/sympy/core/decorators.py", line 132, in binary_op_wrapper return func(self, other) File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/56.412575950366508090/sympy/sympy/core/expr.py", line 172, in __rpow__ return Pow(other, self) File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/56.412575950366508090/sympy/sympy/core/cache.py", line 95, in wrapper retval = func(*args, **kwargs) File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/56.412575950366508090/sympy/sympy/core/power.py", line 286, in __new__ obj = b._eval_power(e) TypeError: unbound method _eval_power() must be called with exp instance as first argument (got Integer instance instead)
```

I tried replacing $\exp$ with just $e$ and received a similar error.

From my solutions page I can see that the answer is $11$. How can I type the expression in order to get $11$ back?

Comment: I believe it's $.5*log(exp(1)**22)$, but anyway you should ask these questions on a stack exchange more relevant to python errors.

Comment: The `exp` function is a function, not the number $e$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use exp as function: `0.5*log(exp(22))`

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. Accepting this once the time limit comes off

Comment: +1. As a Python user, I can confirm that's the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need a calculator.

Note that $\ln(e) = 1$ as $e^1 = e$. Recall also that $\log_b (x^n) = n \log_b (x).$ Thus $\frac{1}{2} \ln(e^{22}) = 11.$

Comment: My first reaction as well—but note that this does NOT answer OP’s question in the slightest.